# synch the contacts on my Android with the current contacts on Google Contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, sony-xperia, google-contacts

I have recently changed number, but kept the same device (Sony Xperia XA1). With the previous number, I saved my contacts in Google Contacts.

Before I changed the sim on my device, I erased some contacts from [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). I formatted the phone and reinstalled applications, logged in with the same google account.

Those "unwanted" contacts are still there. Even though I erased them from Google Contacts website (and I checked the website, they are no longer there).

I tried to log off that google account and in again, because I thought it was a matter of synch. But nothing changed.

So my question is, how to synch the contacts on my Android with ***just*** the current contacts on Google Contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log out from your google account.
2. Delete all contacts - make sure all contacts are deleted from all sources.
3. Log in to your google account

There is a auto - backup and restore option (Find more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)). There is possibility that your device may restore the contacts that were deleted just before the formatting.